# Loading icon not disappearing after a 2.5 seconds

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I have this website and I want the loading icon to look like the Disney+ one. https://mandalorian.elliott23.repl.co/. This is the website, only the loading icon is showing and the actual page is not showing up.
This is the JavaScript and relevant CSS and HTML.

```css
.loader-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.loader-wrapper.invis {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```js
function $(qry){return document.querySelector(qry);}
setTimeout(() => {
  $(".loader-wrapper").classList.add("invis")
}, 2500)
```

```html
<div class="loader-wrapper">
  <img src="+load.svg" width="120px">
</div>
```

I tried using things from past websites (https://cube.elliott23.repl.co) and it didn't work. It has worked with other websites. I don't know if it is because I am using an image or not. Help would be very appreciated.

Comment: The provided code works fine for me, can you provide a reproducible example as either a StackSnippet or JSFiddle that folks can take a look at?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/359ekmfx/ It seems to work in the JS Fiddle, but I am using Replit and it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried putting your function in the console and it worked. It seems like the issue is that your function is not being run, therefore not actually adding the `invis` class.

Comment: @ElliottD'Orazio I'll simplify. You are not running your JavaScript on your website. 

When you go to https://cube.elliott23.repl.co/ and inspect the source, you see that there is a `<script>` tag with the needed JavaScript, which does not exist on the other website.

Comment: Ok, I always forget to do that. Now it works. Thanks, much appreciated.